# .htaccess url to get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a small api,
I have a folder named api inside that folder I have `index.php` and `.htaccess`
What I am trying to do is when I am accessing `api/something` to transform last parameter to `api/?x=something`
And check in php if function `something` exist call it if no show 404.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

If access `api` folder it works but if I add `api/something` no.

If it is Important:
the structure of folders is like this:
`root_website_folder/sub_folder/api`
When it rewrites 'something' to `x=something`
I get the `x`  to call func name if exist

```
public function init(){
        $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST['x'])));
        var_dump($func);
        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0){
            $this->$func();
        }else{
            $this->response('', 401);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you go to **/api/something/** ?

Comment: @starkeen it shows 404

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect to happen when you navigate to `/api/?x=something` should it be further rewritten?

Comment: @apokryfos updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added a rule for the api specifically. 
The following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

This works by excluding /api requests from being captured by the `^(.*)$` rule.

In general you can test your rewrite rules at http://htaccess.mwl.be/ (not affiliated with this, I just find it useful).

Comment: If you exclude the uri **/api** then the rule wont rewrite **/api/something** to **index.php**

Comment: @starkeen I must have misunderstood the question, I thought that was the intention. The `/api/something` requests trigger the second rule.

Comment: @starkeen @apokryfos
My initial `.htaccess` works if I add `api/index.php/somthing` but doesnt convert `something` to `x=something`

Comment: @Froxz you don't mention anything about `api/index.php/...` in the question and don't specify if the file exists or not. That completely changes the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following with RewriteBase directive :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?x=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite **/api/something** to **/api/index.php?x=something**